# Is purrr::map too magical?

Tags: r, purrr

Applying functions in a loop fashion with `purrr::map` is super handy, but extrating objects by its indices seems *"too magical"* to me, for example, the r.squared from lm summary method. How does it work internally?

```
library(tidyverse)
data("mtcars")
mtcars %>% 
  nest(data = -c(vs)) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)),
         summary = map(model, summary),
         r2 = map_dbl(summary, "r.squared"))

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#      vs data               model  summary       r2
#   <dbl> <list>             <list> <list>     <dbl>
# 1     0 <tibble [18 x 10]> <lm>   <smmry.lm> 0.672
# 2     1 <tibble [14 x 10]> <lm>   <smmry.lm> 0.726
```

Comment: it probably chooses action based on argument `.f`. If it is character or integer it just extracts corresponding vector value.

Comment: I see. Don't you think this dual purpuse of the map function has the potential of causing a lot of confusion? I've noticed that there is another purrr function to extract list elements: `pluck`.

Comment: I dont know internal implementation but it is just my guess. `pluck` is not loop version so there is no confusion.